# PostgresSQL: Trigger comparison for json keys

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which has a json type column for a data like this `{"aa":"12:00", "bb":"12:00", "cc":"12:00"}`.

I want to create a trigger which compares if an OLD and a NEW row contains same keys in json column.

What is the best way to do it?

I tried with `is distinct from` but it causes some problems.

`CREATE TRIGGER update_time_stamp
  BEFORE UPDATE ON exampletable
  FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (json_object_keys(NEW.jsoncolumn) IS DISTINCT FROM json_object_keys(OLD.jsoncolumn))
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_stamp();`

Comment: What problems does it cause?

Comment: Updating this json type column causes error `ERROR:  functions and operators can take at most one set argument`